# help to find radius

Tags: geometry

How do I solve this problem mathematically? What is the radius??
Knowing an arc length with a subtended chord (or opening) of known length. It will look like the letter "C". Say an arc length of 8 inches and an opening of 2 inches. I originally thought "give me 5 minutes" but I am stumped. I put it on autocad and arrived at a solution but, that's cheating.

Comment: You need the angle, too.

Comment: Figure out formulas for arc length and chord length based on angle and radius.  (Draw a picture and apply trig definitions and it is obvious.)  Apply these two formulas and you will get the radius and angle with no problem.

Comment: It would be an easy solution with an angle. Are you implying that there is not a mathematical solution? I would be ok with that, it is the not knowing (if there is a solution) that is bothering me.

Comment: I am a machinist. Received a job to roll an 8” length of sheet metal with a 2” opening. This is where this exercise originated from. I know the point is moot but it bothers me to no end when I get my butt kicked on a problem that at first glance seems simple.

Comment: Is the length of the opening along the circle (curved) or the chord (straight)?

Answer (score 1):

We have that the angle of the arc $\alpha=8/R$; we also have that the length of chord $d=2 R\sin{\frac{2\pi-\alpha}{2}}=2 R\sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$. Substituting $\alpha$ in the second equation, we get $2=2R \sin(4/R)$ or $1=R \sin{(4/R)}$. I don't think we can solve this analytically but using numeric methods it seems that $R \approx 1.62$

Comment: It could be interesing if you clarify d=2Rsin(pi-a/2)=2Rsin(a/2)

Comment: @pasabaporaqui: if you connect the center of the circle with the ends of the chord, you get an isosceles triangle which leg is a radius and vertex angle is $\alpha$. Then we draw a height which will also be a median of the chord.

Comment: yes, I do not say thay your answer was wrong (I think it is not). It is only that you name alpha to both, the arc angle and the chord angle, when they are two different ones, adding a total of pi

Comment: @pasabaporaqui: without a drawing it's a little unclear whether it's the same angle or not, there are two possible cases.

Comment: according to your answer, the circle has a length of around 10. The arch is 8, thus is bigger than 180°. The chod of 2 must be the remainder angle.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui: the remaining angle is $2\pi - \alpha$ but $\sin(\pi-\alpha/2)=\sin(\alpha/2)$

Comment: yes, this one is the expression I suggest to add to the answer. It doesn't changes the result (I repeat I agree the answer is thr correct one) but it mades it easier to understand and coherent in notation with other answers.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui: Thank you for your suggestions, I made edits accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider the equation $$1=R \sin \left(\frac{4}{R}\right)$$ let $x=\frac 1 R$ to make $$x=\sin(4x)$$ Graphing, we can see the root "close" to $\frac \pi 6$ (in fact, it is very close to $\frac \pi 5$ but the values of trigonometric functions of this angle are not very pleasant).

We can build the $[1,2]$ Padé approximant around this value and get, *as an approximation*,
$$x-\sin(4x)=\frac{\left(405 \sqrt{3}-189 \pi +6 \sqrt{3} \pi ^2\right)+\left(-3186+168 \sqrt{3} \pi
   +8 \pi ^2\right) y } {\left(36 \sqrt{3} \pi -810\right)+\left(504 \sqrt{3}+48 \pi \right) y-3456
   y^2 }$$ where $y=x-\frac \pi 6$. The numerator cancels for 
$$y=\frac{3 \pi  \left(63-2 \sqrt{3} \pi \right)-405 \sqrt{3}}{8 \pi  \left(21
   \sqrt{3}+\pi \right)-3186}\approx 0.0958952\implies x\approx 0.619494 \implies R\approx 1.61422$$ while the exact solution (obtained using Newton method) would be $R\approx 1.61644$.

**Edit**

Let $x=\frac t4$ and use the magnificent approximation
$$\sin(t) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -t) t}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -t) t}\qquad (0\leq t\leq\pi)$$ which was proposed by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician (that is to say more than $1400$ year ago). We then need to solve
$$\frac t4=\frac{16 (\pi -t) t}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -t) t}\implies t^3+(16-\pi ) t^2+\left(\frac{5 \pi ^2}{4}-16 \pi \right) t=0$$ Solving the quadratic leads to
$$t=-8+\frac{\pi }{2}+\frac{1}{8} \sqrt{4096+512 \pi -64 \pi ^2}\approx 2.47378 \implies x\approx 0.618445\implies R\approx 1.61696$$

Answer (score -1):

If the chord (length 2) has internal angle of $\theta $ then the chord and two radii make an isoceles triangle.

So chord length is $2*r\sin \frac \theta 2=2$.

The outer arch (length 8) has an internal angle of $2\pi -\theta $.  So the arch length is a fraction of the circles circumference.

So arch length is $\frac {2\pi -\theta }{2\pi}*(2\pi*r)=(2\pi -\theta)r= 8$.

There's no real algebraic way to solve this but

$\frac {(2\pi - \theta)*r}{2*r\sin \frac \theta 2}=\frac {(2\pi - \theta)}{2\sin \frac \theta 2}=\frac 82 =4$

Or $2\pi - \theta  = 8\sin {\frac \theta 2}$ which will have distinct solutions only one of which will be between $0$ and $\pi$.

Using a [programable calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2pi+-+x+%3D+8(sin+x%2F2)) we get $\theta \approx 1.33403$.

So $2*r*\sin \frac {1.33403}2 = 2$

$r = \frac 1 {\sin \frac{1.33403}2} \approx 1.6164397972135262367472993714066$

But you know.... I probably have an error somewhere.

$(2\pi - 1.33403)*1.6164397972135262367472993714066\approx 8$.  .... Yeah, this time it's probably correct....

Comment: You don't understand because it's obviously not true and I obviously made a stupid error.

Comment: Well.  so....?  You are correct and I am wrong then....  Figure out where my error is and fix it.